# Is this the correct structure of an Interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to understand the concept of an interface in java so far what I understand is that an interface is java is.

That an interface as below constructs a formal contract between to parties, party A the developer of the interface and party B, the user of the class developed by party B. That any class created that implements the interface must provide the behavior provided by the interface created by Party A.

An object instance created from a class that implements the class will be able to have functionality / behaviour / sub rounties run on that are contained by the interface?

And that an interface acts also as a blue print for the class?
And that an interface should be coded to and not coded from?

```
package house;

public interface Infratructure {
     public int numberBedrooms();
     public int numberBathrooms();

     public boolean attic();
     public int atticSize();

     public boolean lounge();
     public int loungeSize();

     public boolean kitchen();
     public int kitchenSize();

     public boolean grarage();
     public int garageSize();

     public boolean basement();
     public int basementSize();

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what question you're asking here. Can you rephrase and emphasize the question?

Comment: Your interface looks fine but your question is not very clear.

Comment: It's also worth to remember that you do not need to declare methods of the interface `public` explicitly. They are all public by default.

Comment: Methods are usually verbs, not nouns. The methods should be named hasBasement() and getBasementSize(), or isBasementAvailable() and getBasementSize(), to respect the JavaBean conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That an interface as below constructs a formal contract between to
>   parties, party A the developer of the interface and party B, the user
>   of the class developed by party B

Really the interface is a formal contract between two components (software), you don't define an interface in base to requirements of programers, instead you must define it in base a software requirements.

> That any class created that implements the interface must provide the
>   behavior provided by the interface created by Party A

Yes the interface define the behavior. So you must have only the public behavior of a group of classes this enforces the concept of encapsulation.

> An object instance created from a class that implements the class will
>   be able to have functionality / behaviour / sub rounties run on that
>   are contained by the interface?

The interface doesn't contain (implement) any behavior, functionality, sub routines. It just declares it. Letting to the classes the work of implementation.

> And that an interface acts also as a blue print for the class? And that an interface 
>   should be coded to and not coded from?

Yes, if you design your system in base a interfaces you will get more granularity and low cohesion of component.